# Slider div position overlapping on another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to slide a div with some text on hover with another div, and need to repeat it three to four times now when i hover mouse on first div area, the slider div comes right place, but if i hove mouse on second div, the slider div come on same position...

[image]

Really appreciate if some one please can fix this...

**Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9TAYn/)** 

here is Jquery code:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dvPanel1").hover(function () {
            $("#downPanel1").stop(false, true).slideDown(100);
        });
        $("#dvPanel1").mouseleave(function () {
            $("#downPanel1").stop(false, true).slideUp(100);
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dvPanel2").hover(function (event) {
            $("#downPane2").stop(false, true).slideDown(300);

        });
        $("#dvPanel2").mouseleave(function (event) {
            $("#downPane2").stop(false, true).slideUp(300);

        });
    });
```

Comment: Pressing `TidyUp` button on jsFiddle do not cause impotence ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is my modified version might help you

http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/9TAYn/4/

```
#downPane2 {
    display:none;
    float:left;
    width:765px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: Aqua;
    top:360px;
    height:175px;
    margin-left:0px;
    z-index:100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please add in margin top to second panel like below

```
 <div id="downPane2" style="margin-top:189px;">
```

let me know if i can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the '#downPanel..' `position:relative`, instead of 'absolute'. Then set top:0px so that the display under the image (the 0px is relative to the image above the panel).

http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/9TAYn/3/

I also updated the fiddle so that you don't have multple `$(document).onReady(..`

Comment: thanks, But i don't want to move bottom div down, The slider div should be overlap on the bottom div. That why i have used "absolute" position...